# Why is Entity Framework producing nested SELECT queries with duplicated SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm using [Entity Framework logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception) to look at the SQL generated by my queries. In many cases the SQL that's produced has SELECT statements operating on subqueries that are identical to the original query.  For example:

The following EF code:

```
context.PodcastItems
.Where(p => p.ID == sourceFeedUpdateItemId)
.Select(p => new NewPodcastItemSubsetDTO
{
   ID = p.ID,
   ItemID = p.ItemID,
   ItemTitle = p.ItemTitle,
   ItemSummary = p.ItemSummary,
   PermalinkUrl = p.PermalinkUrl,
   ItemPublishedDate = p.ItemPublishedDate,
   AudioFileUrl = p.AudioFileUrl,
   FileSize = p.FileSize,
   Duration = p.Duration
}).SingleOrDefault();
```

generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT
    [Limit1].[ID] AS [ID],
    [Limit1].[ItemID] AS [ItemID],
    [Limit1].[ItemTitle] AS [ItemTitle],
    [Limit1].[ItemSummary] AS [ItemSummary],
    [Limit1].[PermalinkUrl] AS [PermalinkUrl],
    [Limit1].[ItemPublishedDate] AS [ItemPublishedDate],
    [Limit1].[AudioFileUrl] AS [AudioFileUrl],
    [Limit1].[FileSize] AS [FileSize],
    [Limit1].[Duration] AS [Duration]
    FROM ( SELECT TOP (2)
        [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID],
        [Extent1].[ItemID] AS [ItemID],
        [Extent1].[ItemTitle] AS [ItemTitle],
        [Extent1].[ItemSummary] AS [ItemSummary],
        [Extent1].[PermalinkUrl] AS [PermalinkUrl],
        [Extent1].[AudioFileUrl] AS [AudioFileUrl],
        [Extent1].[FileSize] AS [FileSize],
        [Extent1].[Duration] AS [Duration],
        [Extent1].[ItemPublishedDate] AS [ItemPublishedDate]
        FROM [dbo].[PodcastItems] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[ID] = @p__linq__0
    )  AS [Limit1]
```

and this code:

```
string content = context.PodcastItems
.Where(p => p.ID == sourceFeedUpdateItemId)
.Select(p => p.ItemContentCleansed)
.SingleOrDefault();
```

produces:

```
SELECT
    [Limit1].[ItemContentCleansed] AS [ItemContentCleansed]
    FROM ( SELECT TOP (2)
        [Extent1].[ItemContentCleansed] AS [ItemContentCleansed]
        FROM [dbo].[PodcastItems] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[ID] = @p__linq__0
    )  AS [Limit1]
SELECT
    [Limit1].[ItemContentCleansed] AS [ItemContentCleansed]
    FROM ( SELECT TOP (2)
        [Extent1].[ItemContentCleansed] AS [ItemContentCleansed]
        FROM [dbo].[PodcastItems] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[ID] = @p__linq__0
    )  AS [Limit1]
SELECT
    [Limit1].[ItemContentCleansed] AS [ItemContentCleansed]
    FROM ( SELECT TOP (2)
        [Extent1].[ItemContentCleansed] AS [ItemContentCleansed]
        FROM [dbo].[PodcastItems] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[ID] = @p__linq__0
    )  AS [Limit1]
SELECT
    [Limit1].[ItemContentCleansed] AS [ItemContentCleansed]
    FROM ( SELECT TOP (2)
        [Extent1].[ItemContentCleansed] AS [ItemContentCleansed]
        FROM [dbo].[PodcastItems] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[ID] = @p__linq__0
    )  AS [Limit1]
SELECT
    [Limit1].[ItemContentCleansed] AS [ItemContentCleansed]
    FROM ( SELECT TOP (2)
        [Extent1].[ItemContentCleansed] AS [ItemContentCleansed]
        FROM [dbo].[PodcastItems] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[ID] = @p__linq__0
    )  AS [Limit1]
```

Sure seems like a lot of extra cycles are spent to accomplish...nothing?

Why might this be happening?

Comment: How did you make entities mapping? edmx file?

Comment: Correct - edmx file.

Comment: @Backs - I was incorrect. My model classes were generated from an existing database by going to Add...New Item...and selecting ADO.NET Entity Data Model.

Answer (score 0):

Check EDMX file, maybe your entity is defined via `DefiningQuery` like this:

```
<!-- SSDL content -->
<edmx:StorageModels>
  <Schema Namespace="SchoolModel.Store" Alias="Self" Provider="System.Data.SqlClient" ProviderManifestToken="2008" xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm/ssdl">
    <EntityContainer Name="SchoolModelStoreContainer">
       <EntitySet Name="GradeReport" EntityType="SchoolModel.Store.GradeReport">
          <DefiningQuery>
            SELECT CourseID, Grade, FirstName, LastName
            FROM StudentGrade
          </DefiningQuery>
      </EntitySet>
```

You need to replace it without `DefiningQuery` with `EntitySet` only:

```
 <EntitySet Name="Course" EntityType="SchoolModel.Store.Course" store:Type="Tables" Schema="dbo" />
```

Read more in [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/designer/advanced/defining-query).